# Layout detail node + ckeditor layout

Tags: 7, nodes, wysiwyg, theming

When I create a node of content type Proposal like this:

[image]

I can add images, paragraphs, ... . But it looks like this on the detail page of the node:

[image]

No image, no paragraphs, ... . What could be the problem of this?

I'm using the Filtered html text format. When I check the html of the paragraph there is no image, nothing. Just text ... .

These are my settings of context filter filtered html:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at your text filter, see this post for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069162/drupal-media-wysiwyg-ckeditor-inserting-image-issues

Comment: I don't get that option that they suggest, and I also don't the image (html) in my source.

Comment: Could you edit your question with the name of the text filter you use on your field and the settings of that text filter that is found under admin/config/content/formats?

Comment: updated my topic

Comment: Have a look at Limit allowed HTML tags, maybe img, p, etc is not allowed tags?

Comment: That was the problem! The img tag wasn't allowed. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16422/discussion-between-pontus-nilsson-and-nielsv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at *Limit allowed HTML tags* in the setting for your text filter. Make sure img is among the allowed HTML tags.

The settings are found under *admin/config/content/formats*.